# Custom loop ordering not working

Tags: loop

I have a custom loop to display the children of a parent page which works well - however, I cant get the ordering of the items to work as I want - I want them to appear in alphabetical order (A>Z). Can anyone help with some mods to the code below to get it to work as I want it?

```
<?php
$ids = array();
$pages = get_pages("parent=".$post->ID);
if ($pages) {
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $ids[] = $page->ID;
    }
}
$paged = (get_query_var("paged")) ? get_query_var("paged") : 1;
$args = array(
    "paged" => $paged,
    "post__in" => $ids,
    "posts_per_page" => 600,
    "post_type" => "page",
    "sort_order" => "ASC",
    "sort_column" => "post_name"
);
query_posts($args);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
```

Comment: you should avoid using `query_posts` at all costs, there are better/easier/safer ways to make custom queries `WP_Query`/`get_posts`/`pre_get_posts`. You could also eliminate the `get_pages` call by using the parent parameter in the query args. Your issue is probably related to the use of `post__in`, those sorting parameters you're trying to use are very odd and non-standard, is there a reason you did not use the normal parameters from the official docs? `order` and `orderby`?

Comment: Just using a custom loop code example I had found previously - if you have a suggestion for a better approach I will happily change.

Comment: Adding `'orderby'   => 'post_name',
        'order' => 'ASC',` has made this work by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
    "sort_order" => "ASC",
    "sort_column" => "post_name"
```

These are not sorting parameters. Use `order` and `orderby` instead as specified in the official documentation:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

Comment: Thanks - yep - just worked that out